# iPhone SDK: Testing for valid string date

Tags: iphone

I want to be able to validate a date.

It's valid entry is 4 characters with a mmyy mask.

I want to make sure that the value entered is indeed a date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mmyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:YOUR_STRING];


If (date) { 
// CORRECT
}
```

Comment: you can try with `[str intValue];`

Comment: your date format should be MMyy. mm is for minute, so 45 is valid and you should also release your dateFormatter

Answer (score 0):

User `NSDateFormatter`'s `-setDateFormat:` and `-dateFromString:` methods. If the string is not in the correct format, you will get `nil` returned from `-dateFromString:`.

Answer (score 0):

This dateFormatter-thing is inconvinient to me since it accepts to many things as valid date. ok, the day after yesus was born is indeed a valid date ;-) and also dateformatter is removing 1 hour from my datestring because it seems to calculate with utc time or so...thats why i like to check for correct dates with regular expressions:

```
[textfield.text rangeOfString:@"^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(19|20)[0-9]{2}" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location == NSNotFound
```

this example is for german date format