# same day of last month ios

Tags: ios, ipad, nscalendar

Is there any way using NSCalender you can get same day of last month?

I am using a calender which shows user 1 month like the iPad calender when they click on the button I want to move to previous month but should  select the same day as before.

I want to just do

```
[components setMonth:([components month] - 1)];
```

but this will create problems when I are moving from a month with 31 days to month with 30 days and selected day is 31st.

I was able to find examples for android but not iOS.

[android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358373/current-day-n-days-is-the-day-of-next-month-or-previous-month)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This will occur with leap years also.... So what you want one day less or one day more? Facebook shows 28th as birthday for 29th Feb born on non-leap years!!!

Comment: what is your requirement if its 31st December on subtracting 1 month what it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119880/how-to-add-one-month-to-an-nsdate).

It's about adding one month, but you could probably do the same with subtracting.

Change

```
[dateComponents setMonth:1];
```

into

```
[dateComponents setMonth:-1];
```

Comment: This might lead to an invalid date. (Dec 31st -> Nov 31st)

Comment: This answer is correct (it won't result in Nov 31st). If you see an incorrect date when you log it, it's probably because `NSDate`'s `description` method formats it as GMT. Make sure that you show both dates with the same time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no obvious "right" answer and no "built-in" answer.

As Chris's "simple" idea may lead to invalid dates, you may have to handle the edge-cases.

Pseudocode to deal with day-month-year:

1. if month = December start with day-1-(year-1), else
   day-(month-1)-year [using dateComponents]
2. check if this a valid date (using NSDateFormatter like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864165/iphone-sdk-testing-for-valid-string-date)
3. repeat subtracting one day until you reach a valid date

Another idea:

```
prevMonthDate = startDate;
Repeat
    prevMonthDate = prevMonthDate - 1 day
Until (Month(prevMonthDate) < Month(startDate) Or Year(prevMonthDate) < Year(startDate))
    And (Day(prevMonthDate) <= Day(startDate))
```

This requires working with NSDate and NSDateComponents, check out the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1).